# Is it possible to log into an existing website with Swift in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app for a website and was wondering if it is possible to make a login page without showing the actual website. So basically, can i make a login page with a `TextField` for an email and a `TextField` for the password, send the data to the website to login and access the website from a custom built Interface to browse the website (not a `UIWebView`). I would assume i need access to admin the website itself but it would be better if i can do it in another way. I hope i was clear enough, it is kind of hard to explain. If you need any additional information, please feel free to ask me.

Also, i am 14 years old and semi new to Swift and Xcode so a in depth answer would be great. I am also new to Stack Overflow so if i did something wrong, please tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually via textfield everyone is making login screen. So you could also create. To auth any user you need Api's.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! So i need access to the website's api's. Ok i think i could work with them on that.

Comment: Go through this URL -> https://savvyapps.com/blog/how-to-build-restful-api-mobile-app

Comment: Ok i'm not 100% sure thats what i need because of the parts i read, this is for creating an app with a database. I need to figure out how to use an already created website's login page in my app without showing the actual site. Correct me if i'm wrong, i didn't read the whole article yet.

Comment: Yes this is possible, you will just have to build the interface and make all the network requests and handle the responses. But since this is Stackoverflow you will not get a fully explained tutorial of how to do that. SO is for technical questions mostly. So you need actual code that we can help you with and debug possibly after you've done some research of your own. In this case please look up resources to build an interface and make network requests / handle responses. There are a ton online. Best of luck.

e.g first thing I goggled: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2hiaoaRBQ0

Comment: Ahh, ok. I knew i must have done something wrong. Thanks for clarifying that Stackoverflow is for help with specific code that isn't working. I did not know that. I could not find anything on the interned related to logging into an existing website, only creating a login page for a specificaly for the app.

Comment: I have found many tutorials like that one but it is not exactly what i need. I will look to see if there is a reddit for stuff like this and come back here if / when i have problems.